# Unable to install seaborn

Tags: python-3.x

I have windows 10 64bit
When I was trying to install seaborn on Pychram (using python 3.6) got:

```
Executed command:

pip install seaborn

Error occurred:
*numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: no lapack/blas resources found*

Proposed solution:
Try to run this command from the system terminal. Make sure that you use the correct version of 'pip' installed for your Python interpreter located at 'C:\Users\ShayG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe'.
```

Might the problem be with pip or the seaborn?

Comment: Do you have all the dependencies for seaborn installed?

Comment: Just check, the one I dont have is 'scipy', but when I'm trying to download I get the same error. (what I got with seaborn)